Issue in rendering the content
I have my backend implementation running on render .com for frontend I am using next js under src I have login and admin-dash that contains page.jsx for both the folders login is getting done and token is generating and according to role or user redirecting on dashboardroute like this https://admin-4-hoom.onrender-api-admin-dashboard but the content on the dashboard page.jsx isn't showing it is throwing 404 error
I try to fetch the response.data but nothing is coming on the page on browser
